# Flutter get CSV file from github

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the content from a github repo csv file to add to my project. I'm using `csv_reader` plugin.

The csv adress: http://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

My code:

```
Future<List<DataRow>> fetchRows() async {

    var myCSV = CSV.from(
    url: 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv',
      delimiter: ",",
      title: false);

    await myCSV.initFinished; 

    fullPrint(myCSV.shape);

    return [];
}

void fullPrint(String text) {
  final pattern = RegExp('.{1,800}');
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

After calling a breakpoint on the CSV get function, `myCSV` is empty as you can see
[image]

Any help on how to get this csv properly?